# Optimize search and insert operations on large volumes of data

Tags: python, performance, csv, memory, optimization

I am developing a program that needs to process large amounts of data, but I want to save that data in a local storage structure first, before migrating it to a database. So, my question is: what would be the best type of file (or local storage structure) to save that data (which is structured, and, for this purpose, let's assume it's just an id and a name), in a way that could be search and insert optimized?

My though was a CSV file, given that the data is structured, and this can save relatively big amounts of data (in this case, I would need around 1000 to 100 000 rows), but I'm not sure if there is anything better out there. My idea is to order the data alphabetically by name, so the search operation would take, in the worst case, O(n). As for the insert operation, I am struggling to find a good solution to insert a row in an alphabetical order directly in a file, given that I can't insert a row between two rows, so I have to overwrite the whole rows after inserting the one I want. (I also thought about reading the whole file into a list and then writing it again, but that is not the best implementation if the file is too big).

So, can anyone give me some thoughts on the best file type to use, and which approach is best for insert and search optimization? Thanks a lot!

(This is my insert algorithm, but it produces random behaviour)

```
def writingOpt(firstName, lastName, birthdate, country):
    try:
        file = open("players.csv", "r+", newline='')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File players.csv not found")
    else:
        with file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            name = firstName + ' ' + lastName
            inserted = False
            previousRow = []
            previousPosition = 0

            for row in reader:
                if name < row[0]:
                    file.seek(previousPosition)

                    if not inserted:
                        previousRow = [name, birthdate, country]
                        inserted = True

                    writer.writerow(previousRow)
                    previousRow = row

                previousPosition += len(','.join(row))
```

Comment: use `pandas` library.

Comment: Unless it's only for learning purpose, you're wasting your time reinventing the proverbial squared wheel - this problem has already been solved by relational databases, and you're not going to do anything better or faster with Python and a csv file.

Comment: @has I will give it a try, thank you!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers What I am trying to accomplish is not exactly "reinventing the wheel" in terms of the concept of relational DB's, but somehow finding a way to save my data temporarily in a local storage structure while finding the best way to structure my DB model, in terms of normalization and diagrams. Because the data I want needs to be scraped from a website that is constantly changing in its structure

Comment: you'll get the same issue with a csv - the csv structure will have to change too. At worst you can extract the constant part of your data (the one you use for searching) in proper db fields and store the rest as a json blob (at least until you find a better solution). Some rdbms now have native support for json fields fwiw, but even if you don't want to worry about a setting up a proper db server you can still use sqlite in the meantime - it's a local storage and it's optimized for search and insertion.

Comment: Yeah, i guess you have a point. I'll just use SQLite to store my temporary data and later project and design a better implemented one! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea of re-implementing databases is good for learning, but most probably terribly bad for production code.

Databases (especially relational) came a long way with tons of optimizations, and it will be really really hard to be somewhere near.

That being said, some notes that may help:

- if possible, process data in-memory, write back to disk. You will suffer all IO, but at least you're not doing seek over disk. As mentioned, `pandas` is good place to start
- 100k is small amount, in terms of modern DBs
- efficiency in reading comes from having data sorted and indexed (btree+ in modern approach), which makes search `O(logN)` instead of `O(N)`. The problem though, its pretty hard to work with IO in low-level, especially if you're using CSV, "single elment" for you is defined by newline chars, so you need to implement high-level seek by yourself
- you can't "insert" data, in terms of how most OS treat IO, because interface is sequential. To avoid `O(N)` on inserts, leverage old trick — write *new* data at the end `O(N)`, and mark old element as deleted somehow. The trick is to be able to write same amount of bytes for marker, i.e. have boolean flag for each row, and implement "smart" logic for reading.

---

Regarding insert trick, here's simple example. Lets assume you have table sorted by `id` and data is like

```
id  name    amount
1   Alice   10
2   Bob     20
3   Charlie 30
```

And you need to update name/amount for `id = 2`. Search is `O(logN)` (if you've implemented proper `.seek`, what happens with actual update? If you're writing exact same amount of bytes, you can write over – seek to proper position and write. I.e. changing `20` to `25` is no problem at all, you write only thing you need (not guaranteed, but let's skip low-level details).
The problem comes when you need to change, let's say, `20` to `120`. In most cases, your storage abstraction is sequential stream of bytes, imagine as

```
id,name,amount\n1,Alice,10\n2,Bob,20\n3,Charlie,30\n  # old
id,name,amount\n1,Alice,10\n2,Bob,120\n3,Charlie,30\n # new
                                    ^ everything beyond this point
                                      needs to be re-written
```

So you'll end up with `O(N/2)` in average (which is, obviously, ~same as `O(N)`)

---

What you can do instead: have a "flag" showing if record is valid now:

```
valid   id  name    amount
Y       1   Alice   10
Y       2   Bob     20
Y       3   Charlie 30
```

When you need to do update, mark old row as "invalid" by flag of same amount of bytes as "valid" flag, and write new row at the end:

```
valid   id  name    amount
Y       1   Alice   10
N       2   Bob     20
Y       3   Charlie 30
Y       2   Bob     120
```

The operation is `O(logN)` to find row (same as before), `O(1)` for overwriting new flag, and `O(M)` for writing new data (seek to the end of file is not free itself, but this is a different story). The drawback – now you need to:

- implement *optimistic search with fallback* – if you seek for data via tree or binary search, you need to check flag state, and if data is obsolete – seek to the end of file and read it in reverse
- as updates come, unoptimized "tail" grows, more and more pushing you towards `O(N)` complexity (btree can help, btw). So you need to eventually *compress* data back into optimal state – re-read all data, drop obsolete rows, re-sort data, and write back to disk. This is what usually referred to as "vacuum" in RDBMS. To do so, you better keep track of "how much rows is re-written" vs "how much rows is there alltogether" – having this ratio above some threshold is a sign to vacuum up.

Comment: Hmm.. I see where you are getting! I also thought about designing a data structure like you mentioned (B-Tree), but I gave up because of the memory problem. But I guess it is always a trade-off between memory and performance, so I'll perform some tests and see how it goes. I didn't quite understand the last point though, what do you mean by writing the new data at the end and having a boolean flag? Could you elaborate? Thank you!

Comment: Wrote a little bit on that optimization

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to store your csv data in a pandas dataframe then sort it alphabetically before saving your dataframe content will be pretty much straight forward.

To work with huge amount of data please refer to the doc : [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Here is a sample of code :

```
# Instanciate your pandas dataframe reading new values  (for 1000 to 100 000 lines you shouldn't encounter any issue)
df = pd.read_csv('players.csv', low_memory=True, sep=';', ...)
# Sort on the column
df.sort('name')
# Then write your sorted data to a csv file :)
df.to_csv('players_sorted.csv', index=False, header=False, sep=';', ...)
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Uau, that seems to be a great idea! I could write the whole data to a csv, appending each registry to the file, and once I was finished, I would just use pandas dataframe to sort it and write it in a new csv file! I will surely give it a try, thanks!